# Graph test connection between two nodes without bfs / dfs

Tags: java, search, graph

I hava a graph implementation in Java which stores all nodes in a List and all Edges in a list.
The Graph can be directed and undirected.

Now I search for a algorithm which test if two given nodes a,b are connected

```
public class Graph {
    private List<Node> nodes;
    private List<Edge> edges;

    boolean hasConnection(Node a, Node b) {
       // TODO implement some Algorithm
    }
}
```

The algorithm can be naive maybe with high complexity.
I dont want to use BFS or DFS, but something which is worser than those algorithms.

Is there a naive or brute force variant?

Comment: BFS and DFS are brute force - they loop over all nodes just in different orders.

Comment: Ok yes you are right. Is there another alternative?

Comment: Compute the transitive closure of the binary relation over the nodes, as defined by your edges.